# Animation of polar gauge takes long route

Tags: highcharts

In my HighCharts/HighStock polar graph, live wind direction data is shown in a wind rose. The incoming data is ranged from 0 to 359 degrees, where 0 degree is North. When the wind varies around the North direction, the incoming data can wrap around the 0/359 border.

When animation is enabled, the gauge travels the long route, from e.g. 1 degree along the E (90), S (180), W (270) to 357 degree.

It would be nice if the animation takes the shortest route, from e.g. 1 degree along 0, 359, 358 to 357 degree.
How can this be done?

Comment: did you try something? cause this question is just asking for help.

Comment: Could you reproduce your current code on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Well @OscarDavid, I got [this](http://raytje.dyndns.pro/anemo.php) working so far. I browsed through the HighCharts API and search the internet for clues, but not succesfull sofar.

Comment: @Ray I think that it will be much easier to find a solution if you reproduce your case on some online editor with two buttons to switch the data which shows the issue which you have described.